# cannot change language in spring application

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-messaging

I'm trying to change language using `<spring:message>` tag. But it doesn't get recognized.

**language.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring"
           uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1><spring:message code="home.title" /></h1>
        <p><spring:message code="home.intro" /></p>
<p>
    <a href="?lang=en">English</a> |
    <a href="?lang=fr">French</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
  @Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.dilini.controller", "com.dilini.service"})
@Import({DatabaseConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class})
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public ViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerInterceptor performanceInterceptor() {
        PerformanceInterceptor interceptor;
        interceptor = new PerformanceInterceptor();
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(performanceInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/user/*");
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/messages");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en"));
        return localeResolver;
    }
}
```

**src/main/resources/messages/en.properties**

```
home.title=Home
home.intro= this is my magnificent intro
```

Likewise the french.

**src/main/resources/messages/fr.properties**

```
home.title=Accueil
home.intro=Splendide page d'accueil,
```

Do I need to add another dependency for this feature? Or there is any issue is the code?

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this below code

```
@Bean(name = "localeResolver")
    public LocaleResolver getLocaleResolver()  {
        CookieLocaleResolver resolver= new CookieLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setCookieDomain("myAppLocaleCookie");
        resolver.setCookieMaxAge(600); 
        return resolver;
    } 

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource messageSource()  {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageResource= new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();         
        // For example: i18n/messages_en.properties
        // For example: i18n/messages_fr.properties
        messageResource.setBasename("classpath:i18n/messages");
        messageResource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageResource;
    }
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        registry.addInterceptor(localeInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/*");
    }
```

Note : messages_en.properties and messages_fr.properties should be present into src/main/resources/i18n

Comment: I already have en.properties and fr.properties files in src/main/resources/messages/ path. How do I change this according to my files

Comment: @pippilongstocking : Rename both file with message_en , message_fr and update messageSource bean code with 

 messageResource.setBasename("classpath:messages/message");

Comment: Yep its working thank you very much. Can you please tell me why I needed to change that file names.

Answer (score 1):

In your appconfig i don't see the interceptor registration. You simply defined it but you never registered it. You should override the `addInterceptors` method

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}
```

Try to add it and check if it works

Comment: So you already have it and it doesn't work. Did i understand correctly?

Comment: are you using spring-boot? May you post all your AppConfig code?

Comment: No. I'm not using spring boot. Okay I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

In your `src/main/resources/messages/` be sur to create both i18 files (en and fr named as below ):

in your  `MessageSource` you just set the `basename` to `messages` `=>` `messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/messages");`

so your local files should be named messages_[local].properties (spring will search for local names file as set in the as `.setBasename()` )

as below

`messages_en.properties` that contains :

```
home.title=Home
home.intro= this is my magnificent intro
```

and `messages_fr.properties` that

```
home.title=Accueil
home.intro= ceci est ma magnifique intro
```

It should work

Comment: in what names? please tell me

Comment: both `en.properties` shoudl be `messages_en.properties` same thing for fr

Comment: @pippilongstocking added explanation why naming file  in my answer

Comment: Thanks you saved me.

Comment: @pippilongstocking I'm Glad , Welcome  :)